# Can I use SSDT to simplify deploying new SQL Tables and Stored Procedures?

Tags: deployment, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I am just finding out about SSDT. I am using Visual Studio 2019.
I have created a whole bunch of new Tables & Stored Procedures to go with an App that I have been developing.
Now I am ready to deploy my App to the live system.
Can I use SSDT to make this easy?
At the moment, I use SSMS to Script my Tables & Stored Procedures as Create to a New Query Window, & then use Save As to save these to my hard drive.
Finally, all the scripts have to be run in the live database.
Can I use SSDT to just do my updates & leave the rest alone?

Comment: you are more likely to get help by showing what you have tried already. Please post some code or at least some of what you have tried.

Comment: I have created a Solution and added 3 SQL Server Database Projects, one for each DB that I have done work on. For each project I have imported the database. There are loads of errors, mostly in views & stored procedures I didn't create. Before I invest too much time in this, I want to know if I can use it just to do my updates to en existing database without affecting the rest.

Comment: you need to fix errors first to be able to deploy. Your project must be buildable